# Get the Top records from each group in MYSQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I've a table **event_log** with the following columns in MYSQL,

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `event_log` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `customer_id` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,    
  `event_time` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=1 ;
```

The sample Data can be,

```
id, customer_id, event_time
1      100       '2015-03-22 23:54:37'    
2      100       '2015-03-21 23:54:37'
3      100       '2015-03-20 23:54:37'  
4      101       '2015-03-19 23:54:37'  
5      102       '2015-03-19 23:54:37'  
6      102       '2015-03-18 23:54:37'  
7      103       '2015-03-17 23:54:37'  
8      103       '2015-03-16 23:54:37'  
9      103       '2015-03-15 23:54:37'  
10     103       '2015-03-14 23:54:37'
```

I want to group on customer_id and then pick the top 2 records from each group using event_time column (whose time is greater)

Please, suggest

Thanks,
Faisal Nasir

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a version that doesn't use variables:

```
select el.*
from event_log el
where 2 >= (select count(*)
            from event_log el2
            where el2.customer_id = el.customer_id and
                  el2.event_time >= el.event_time
           );
```

This could even have reasonable performance with an index on `event_log(customer_id, event_time)`.

Answer (score 0):

One way to use user defined variables to pick 2 recent entries per customer_id

```
SELECT `id`, `customer_id`, `event_time`,row_num
FROM (
SELECT *,
@r:= CASE WHEN @g = `customer_id` THEN @r +1  ELSE 1  END row_num,
@g:= `customer_id`
FROM event_log 
CROSS JOIN(SELECT @g:= NULL,@r:=0) a
ORDER BY `customer_id`,`event_time` desc  
) t 
where row_num <= 2
```

[`DEMO`](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/87e10/4)